# I want get settings control of EDGE

Tags: microsoft-edge

In EDGE navigator in edge://settings/personalinfo windows there is a checkbox:

"Save and fill basic info"

I need this in "off" mode, because autocomplete attribute on off have a limited scope for this feature in EDGE, I need control from javascript, there any chance to configure this from javascript?

Is a any API navigator from reach this settings or what is your recomendation? Of course the final user is no able to change this manually. Must be programatically done.

[image]

Comment: Search with Google to see if there is a registry key or group policy setting  for this.  If nothing turns up you can use a registry snapshot and differencing tool to see if it can spot a change when you toggle it off and on.  Note that many Windows settings are now protected against programmatic changes for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by community members, there is a corresponding group policy or registry control for this browser setting, you can simply refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#autofilladdressenabled):

Group Policy (ADMX) info

- GP unique name: AutofillAddressEnabled
- GP name: Enable AutoFill for addresses
- GP path (Mandatory): Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge/

Windows Registry Settings

- Path (Mandatory): SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge
- Path (Recommended): SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\Recommended
- Value Name: AutofillAddressEnabled
- Value Type: REG_DWORD

> I need this in "off" mode, because autocomplete attribute on off have a limited scope for this feature in EDGE, I need control from javascript, there any chance to configure this from javascript?

Due to browser security issues, you cannot modify local file content(these configuration) through client-side scripts.